# 'CSRFTokenField' object is not iterable - Flask, WTForms

Tags: python, sqlite, flask, flask-wtforms, wtforms

Basically I'm trying to create a survey that assesses some skills a person has. I'm using flask for the website, wtforms for the RadioField, and sqlite for the database. Here's my sqlite code:

```
CREATE TABLE questions (
  q_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
  skill TEXT NOT NULL,
  question TEXT NOT NULL
);
```

To help me solve this you can just insert any values you want, the values don't matter.

My python code:

```
from flask import (
    Blueprint, flash, g, redirect, render_template, request, session, url_for
)

from wtforms import RadioField, SubmitField
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm

bp = Blueprint('website', __name__)

def get_questions():
    questions = get_db().execute(
        'SELECT skill, question FROM questions'
    )
    return questions

@bp.route('/questions', methods=('GET',))
def questions():
    form = Quiz()
    questions = get_questions()
    for question in questions:
        setattr(form, question["skill"], RadioField(u"{}".format(question["question"]), choices=[("0","Strongly disagree"),("0","Disagree"),("1","Neither agree nor disagree"),("2","Agree"),("3","Strongly agree")]))
    return render_template('questions.html', questions=form)
```

This is my html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Testing</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form method="post" action="/submit">
      {% for question in questions %}
        {% if question.type == "RadioField" %}
          {{ question.label }}
          {% for subfield in question %}
            <tr>
            <td>{{ subfield }}</td>
            <td>{{ subfield.label }}</td>
            </tr>
          {% endfor %}
        {% endif %}
      {% endfor %}
      {{ questions.submit }}
    </form>

  </body>
</html>
```

The problem is that only the submit button shows up, nothing else. If I try changing == "RadioField" to != "SubmitField", then I get the following error: 'CSRFTokenField' object is not iterable.

Edit: this is my class form:

```
class Quiz(FlaskForm):
    submit = SubmitField()
```